# Вставка данных из массива

Tags: jquery

Это массив:

```
"Serebro","Элджей","MATRANG","HammAli","IVAN VALEEV","Jah Khalib","RASA","Тима Белорусских","Grivina","Егор Крид","Леша Свик","Артем Качер","Монеточка","Miyagi","Imagine Dragons","Ariana Grande","Время и Стекло","Artik & Asti","Filatov & Karas","MBAND","Ленинград","ВИА Гра","Дима Билан","Artik pres. Asti","Егор Крид","Мот","Баста","Григорий Лепс","Макс Корж","Ханна","T1One","Макс Барских","Руки Вверх","Ани Лорак","Стас Михайлов","Полина Гагарина","CYGO","Елена Темникова","Филипп Киркоров","Skillet","Linkin Park","Ольга Бузова","Guf","Юлия Савичева","Сергей Лазарев","Натали","Светлана Лобода","Armin Van Buuren","Evanescence","Scorpions","Bahh Tee","Андрей Леницкий","Jah Khalib"
```

Это элемент: `<span class="author"></span>`

**Вопрос:** Как каждую минуту:

```
setInterval(function() {
   ....
}, 60000);
```

брать **случайное значение** из массива и заменять текст в объекте `.author`, чтобы не было повторений удалять значение из массива, а когда массив опустеет, то оставлять последнее сохранённое значение?

Comment: `let author = authors[Math.floor(Math.random()*authors.length)];`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Поставил смену текста каждую секунду, чтобы было наглядно.

```js
var arr = ["Serebro","Элджей","MATRANG","HammAli","IVAN VALEEV"];
var elem = document.getElementsByClassName('author')[0];

var interval = setInterval(function() {
    if(arr.length > 0) {
        var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * arr.length);
     elem.innerText = arr.splice(rand, 1);
    } else {
     clearInterval(interval);      
    }
}, 1000);
```

```html
<span class="author"></span>
```